# set_adminrole() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

so I'm trying to create a setup command in my bot where the user can choose what he wants. The problem is I can' get it to work as I want to.

I have this as my code

```
# Function to write changes to file
def set_adminrole(guild: Guild, *, role: Role):
    with open("admins.json") as f:
        roles = json.load(f)

    roles[str(guild.id)] = role.id

    with open("admins.json", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(roles, f, indent=4)

# Actual command

-- Not important code --

await ctx.send(f"Now, mention the role you want it to be the admin role")
    role: Message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    set_adminrole(ctx.message.guild, role.content)
    await ctx.send(f"Admin role changed to {Role(role.content).mention}... Let's keep going")
```

When I mention a role and try to call the function with it it gives me this error:
`TypeError: set_adminrole() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`role` is a keyword-only parameter, as it follows the `*` in the parameter list. You need to pass the value as a keyword argument, not a positional argument.

```
set_adminrole(ctx.message.guild, role=role.content)
```

Comment: I changed what you told me, and made some tweaks. Now I have
`await ctx.send(f"Now, mention the role you want it to be the admin role")
    role: Message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    actualrole = Role(role)
    set_adminrole(ctx.message.guild, role=actualrole)
    await ctx.send(f"Admin role changed to {Role(role.content).mention}... Let's keep going")` And now I have this `File "D:/Ficheiros/Pastas/Tudo/Coding/Python/Projects/Server-Utils/bot.py", line 262, in start_setup
    actualrole = Role(role)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: holy sh*t this is unreadable... 
This is the code: https://hastebin.com/kinayebogi.py and this is the error: https://hastebin.com/payebitiqe.sql

Comment: This is a whole new problem, and should be posted as a separate question.